# How to set a default value for a JSON column/attribute in a Rails active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

I have something like this class

```rb
#  json_column  :json
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def name=(val)
    json_column[:name] = val
  end

  def name
    json_column[:name]
  end
end
```

It works fine when I load data, but if I create a new instance like `MyClass.new(name: "foo")` my problems begins...

If I let it as it is, it will trhow an exception in the `name=` because nil is not a hash :).

If I try to initialize the json_column in the after_initialize method

```rb
after_initialize { self.json_column ||= {}  }
```

It also don't work because it seems that the `after_initialize` is called after set the parameters

Does someone have some hint how should I fix this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not in the migration? You'll save a lot of time as Active Record Callbacks are a pain in the ass.

Comment: Hi @SebastianPalma, you mean as the **default** value? Unfortunately it is not possible set a **default** value to a json column

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use store then after_initialize callbacks like this to assign default values

```
    store :json_column_name, accessors: [:key_name], coder: Hash # in mysql

    store_accessor :json_column_name, [:key_name] # in psql

    after_initialize :initialize_defaults, :if => :new_record?

    def initialize_defaults
        self.key_name = value
    end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to work...  Let me make some other tests so Ill mark as the best answer

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much.  Do you know if  is there some way to convert symbols to string in the setter? I backtrack the code until https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb#L138 , but after this it become supercomplex